# Will a .net Core DeflateStream always produce the same result for a given input?

Tags: .net-core, compression, zlib

If I use a .net-core DeflateStream, that uses zlib, to compress a string:

Will the resulting byte array always be the same if the original string has the same content?

It will only be used within an application, so not on different os:es or frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

"Always" is a *very* long time. So no. It will not always produce the same result, even with the same compression settings. Eventually the code will change and produce different output.

Of course, you can get different output right now from the same code and version of that code simply by choosing a different compression level. So doubly no.

Comment: OK, badly worded question. I was thinking of using the compressed string instead of a hash, so all input for compressing would be the same, over a short period of time anyway.

Comment: Again, you can never rely on getting the same compressed output. All that needs to happen is for the software to be updated, and now the output is different. All that is ever guaranteed is that the _decompressed_ output and compression and decompression will be exactly the same as the original data. Period.